# find which friends of user like facebook "PAGE"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook page and few apps built for it, and obviously have few fans of the page.

I'd like to know which friends of the currently logged in user (who is already my fan) are also my fan, i.e. find out how many users in current user's friend list are fans of my page.

I've tried  to use `friends.getappusers`, but its deprecated.

FQL:

```
SELECT uid FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ?)
AND is_app_user = 1
```

--again an app usage.

OLD API: `$facebook->api_client->friends_getAppUsers();`

GRAPH API: `$facebook->api(array('method' => 'friends.getAppUsers'));`

I Know an app can do this.. but that wont help, I want the page to likes to be measured and not the app likes or usage..

Comment: ok.. if its now edited and done.. can it be resolved please..?